# Identifier value displays in NSTableView

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstableview

I am using NSTableView to display the values received from the json. The values getting fine from json, but while displaying the output will be like this..[image]

The code will be here:

//tValues is a class object

```
tValues  = [[tableValues alloc] initWithGroupTableValue:[groupIDPHP objectAtIndex:i] withGroupName:[groupNamePHP objectAtIndex:i] withGroupDesc:[groupDescPHP objectAtIndex:i] withGroupStatus:[groupStatusPHP objectAtIndex:i]];
[listGroup addObject:tValues];
[managerTable reloadData];



- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)aRowIndex
{
    NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld",[aTableColumn identifier], (long)aRowIndex];
    return cellValue;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return [groupIDPHP count];
    }
```

//tValues class

```
-(id)initWithGroupTableValue:(NSString *)groupID withGroupName:(NSString *)groupName withGroupDesc:(NSString *)groupDesc withGroupStatus:(NSString *)groupStatus{

    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        tGroupId = [groupID copy];
        tGroupName = [groupName copy];
        tGroupDesc = [groupDesc copy];
        tGroupStatus = [groupStatus copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Can anybody help to solve this problem?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of

`- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)aRowIndex
{
    NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld",[aTableColumn identifier], (long)aRowIndex];
    return cellValue;
}`

Does exactly what you are seeing. 
It is working as coded. You need to change what you are returning as a string here to see anything different.

Comment: I need to return the string if the identifiers are matched

Comment: Not exactly. All you need to do is return the string you want to display when it matches. This method is where you determine what data to populate a cell.

Comment: for that which method i have to use?

Comment: It depends on what your data structure looks like.